# How to resize a Graph element after window resize in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

I have a GUI in Python using PySimpleGUI with a `Graph` element (drawing canvas) on it. I want the user to be able to resize the window. The drawing (`Graph` element) should resize along with the window (as well as all the drawing elements on the `Graph` element).

I tried the following code, but the resizing doesn't work. Either  the circle remains the same size in pixels, regardless of the window size (current code) or the circle does resize, but resizing the Graph element triggers a Window resize event by itself (uncomment line 13 with the `graph.set_size()` method)

Question: how to resize the `Graph` element together with the Window, and also resize the elements on the `Graph` canvas. In the example code: I want the circle to resize so that it fits inside the window.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg


INIT_SIZE_PX = (100, 100)
COORD_SYSTEM = [(0, 0), (2, 2)]
CIRCLE_CENTER = (1, 1)
CIRCLE_RADIUS = 1
CIRCLE_COLOR = 'red'


def draw_graph(graph, size):
    graph.erase()
    # graph.set_size(size)  # NOT the way, triggers resize events on its own
    # graph.change_coordinates(*COORD_SYSTEM)  # Not necessary
    graph.draw_circle(CIRCLE_CENTER, CIRCLE_RADIUS, fill_color=CIRCLE_COLOR)


layout = [[
    sg.Graph(INIT_SIZE_PX, *COORD_SYSTEM, key='graph',
             expand_x=True, expand_y=True)
]]
window = sg.Window('Window title', layout=layout,
                   finalize=True, resizable=True)
window.bind('<Configure>', "Resize_Event")
draw_graph(window['graph'], window.size)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break

    elif event == "Resize_Event":
        new_size = (int(window.size[0] * 0.9), int(window.size[1] * 0.9))
        draw_graph(window['graph'], new_size)
        print(f"Resized to: {window.size=}; {window['graph'].Size=}")

window.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, only the coordinate changed for all the items on  Graph element, all other features kept the same, like line width, image, text.
If more detail update for items on Graph element required, maybe you need to write the code for `graph.widget.scale` method.

```py
from random import randint
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def random_color():
    return '#%02X%02X%02X' % (randint(0,255), randint(0,255), randint(0,255))

size = (640, 480)
layout = [
    [sg.Graph(size, (0, 0), size, background_color='green', expand_x=True, expand_y=True, pad=(0, 0), key='Graph')],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Plot')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, resizable=True, margins=(0, 0), finalize=True)
graph, plot = window['Graph'], window['Plot']

## Change the pack order of Graph (row frame) to laste one.
graph_row_frame_pack_info = graph.widget.master.pack_info()
plot_row_frame_pack_info = plot.widget.master.pack_info()
plot_row_frame_pack_info['side'] = 'bottom'
plot.widget.master.pack(**plot_row_frame_pack_info)
graph.widget.master.pack(**graph_row_frame_pack_info)

graph.bind('<Configure>', ' Configure')

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Graph Configure':
        e = graph.user_bind_event
        w0, h0 = graph.CanvasSize
        # Update the canvas size for coordinate conversion
        w1, h1 = graph.CanvasSize = e.width, e.height
        w_scale, h_scale = w1/w0, h1/h0
        graph.widget.scale("all", 0, 0, w_scale, h_scale)
    elif event == 'Plot':
        graph.erase()
        graph.draw_rectangle((100, 100), (540, 380), fill_color=random_color())
        graph.draw_arc((100, 380), (540, 430), 180, 180, fill_color=random_color())
        graph.draw_circle((320, 240), 140, fill_color=random_color())
        graph.draw_image(data=sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_LAUGH, location=(100, 380))
        graph.draw_text('Hello World', location=(320, 240))

window.close()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Oh!  Didn't know about the scale method.  Very very nice!